# CiviCRM 4.6.7 Wordpress 4.3 Extension Issue / BaseURL

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, extension

Went through the install twice and it is repeatable on my shared hosting server.

The extensions are expecting to rewrite: wp/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

But the it is actually here: wp/index.php/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

(wp/ is the base install of my wordpress)

It seems Wordpress 4.3 is injecting the index.php file to be rewritten and CiviCRM does not like this. I am having to create amended menu items with the corrected URL, but would like to know if there is a better way to handle this?

I tried changing some of the base url configurations, but then I break the main CiviCRM components and have to restore them manually.

Comment: Have you set your WordPress permalink structure?

Comment: I did not, it was a new install of Wordpress 4.3 and CiviCRM.

Comment: After you mentioned it, I did check permalinks and it was set to insert the index.php. That seems to be what it needed!

Answer (score 2):

This is as @Christian-Wach suggested. For some reason a permalink was set injecting the index.php in a new install of both Wordpress and CiviCRM.

So check your permalinks inside Wordpress in addition to BaseURL.